# JSON javascript date time format

Tags: javascript, json

I have this date-time format in my json
**'2019-12-15T16:00:50.913Z'**

how do i turn it into this:

**'December 15, 2019, 4:00 PM'**

thanks

Comment: With this https://date-fns.org/

Comment: See also [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var dateStr = "2019-12-15T16:00:50.913Z";
var date = new Date(dateStr);
```

Output: `Sun Dec 15 2019 16:00:50 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)`

It won't output exactly what you said but it will be readable and it's an easy way of doing it.

Further information: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/jan/06/javascript-json-date-parsing-and-real-dates#decoding-the-date